# Destructuring Assignment to Pass an Object as a Function's Parameters in Javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript, destructuring

In a course, I use destructuring:

```js
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

const half = ({min, max}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

I first thought the right syntax would be (which also works):

```
const half = ({min, max} = stats) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

My question is how JS knows in which object to look for `min` and `max` and what would happen in the event of another object `stats2` having properties `min` and `max` as well? I don't understand the behaviour of the code in that case.

Comment: To *pass* an object to the function, you need to *call* the function, which you're not doing in the posted code. Please show that as well.

Comment: `= stats` is a parameter default initialiser and has nothing to do with destructuring per se.

Comment: Javascript only does what you tell it to do. So you have to specify which object to look inside of like `stats.min` and `stats2.min`. Sorry if I'm not understanding your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the method `half` you are writing like this,

```
half(stats);
```

So, JS knows the object you passed for half method. Therefore js will look for min, max keys in the passed object if you declare the half method like this,

```
const half = ({min, max}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

For another object stats2, you would again call the half method the following way,

```
half(stats2);
```

Lets say you have 2 params for half method like,

```
const half = ({min, max}, {foo,bar}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

Now if you call the half method with both your stats and stats2 object,

```
half(stats, stats2);
```

It will first take the min and max from stats and try to find `foo and bar` from stats2.

Comment: I indeed completely forgot the function call, silly me! Thanks for the extended explanation, this clarifies it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`half` is an arrow function. Now, to use `half` that you defined, you would need to pass an object like that `half(myObject)`. When `half` receives this `myObject` it takes the `min` and `max` values out of it. If the provided object does not contain these values, then it will substitute the missing value with `undefined`.

To answer your question, JS will look for `min` and `max` only in that object that is passed to your `half` function. Therefore, other objects that are defined outside the scope of `half` will not be touched.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer, I indeed forgot about the function call. Rookie mistake.